# How to create a UserControl with property capable of binding to collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have created an extension of a chart control, and I have declared following property:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

Now, when I try to use it in binding

```
<chart:DataChart ItemsSource="{Bind MySource}"/>
```

I am getting:

```
error MC3074: The tag 'Bind' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
```

What should I change for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to use `Binding`, not `Bind`. (Perhaps just a misspelling.)
2. In order to use `Binding` for `ItemsSource`, it has to be a [dependency property](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html#creation).